# Serializing DateTime property to work in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, datetime, json.net

I have a List of c# objects that have a DateTime property, I serialize this using NewtonSoft

```
result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject( PagedZoningCases );
```

this makes the DateTime come out as:

> CallDateTime: "2017-04-17T17:06:00"

but that's no good in javascript, so I tried the following

```
result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject( PagedZoningCases, new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.JavaScriptDateTimeConverter);
```

this is a bit better it produces the following:

> CallDateTime: "new Date(1396496760000)"

when I return the result to the page and in javascript do JSON.parse(result) it throws an error

I performed the following test to see what javascript expects:

```
    var date = new Date();
    console.log(date); //Thu Nov 21 2019 15:29:33 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
    var json = JSON.stringify(date);
    console.log(json); //"2019-11-21T02:29:33.392Z"
    var date2 = new Date(dateStr);
    console.log(date2); //Thu Nov 21 2019 15:29:33 GMT+1300 (New Zealand Daylight Time)
```

So NewtonSoft's convertor doesn't seem to be converting the date to the right value to work inside the Date() function. It gives it the milliseconds past epoch, but javascript isn't expecting that.

What can I do to serialize a DateTime from c# and parse it via JSON to a javascript date object?

Comment: Can you not just parse the formatted date from your JSON like so `var date = new Date(Date.parse(myDateString))`? The first format you listed will parse correctly.

Comment: I'm parsing a collection of objects not a one off date string

Comment: Yes the first does parse but I would like it to be inside the collection as: CallDateTime: new Date(2019-11-21T02:29:33.392Z) and that would mean altering how it is serialized

Comment: @Hank, did my answer help you solve your issue? If so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to help further.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've got a missing step somewhere, because on the face of it, you're doing everything right. So let me outline the required steps here:

1. You have a class with a property of `DateTime` type, e.g. `PagedZoningCase`:

   ```
   public class PagedZoningCase
   {
       public DateTime CallDateTime { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. You have an object of type `PagedZoningCase`, and you serialize it using the code:

   ```
   var records = new List<PagedZoningCase> { new PagedZoningCase { CallDateTime = DateTime.Now } };
   var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(records);
   ```
3. You get a json which looks like this:

   ```
   "[{\"CallDateTime\":\"2019-11-26T14:28:35.5185231+02:00\"}]"
   ```
4. On client side, you parse this json, and use `Date` constructor because [JSON does not know anything about dates](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/jan/06/javascript-json-date-parsing-and-real-dates):

   ```
   var json = "[{\"CallDateTime\":\"2019-11-26T14:28:35.5185231+02:00\"}]";
   var records = JSON.parse(json);
   var recordsWithDates = records.map(function (r) { 
      r.CallDateTime = new Date(r.CallDateTime); 
      return r;
   });
   ```

And that's it. You can validate you have a `Date` type like so (BTW, don't try to print dates in StackOverflow console, as it only prints a string):

```js
var json = "[{\"CallDateTime\":\"2019-11-26T14:28:35.5185231+02:00\"}]";
var records = JSON.parse(json);
var recordsWithDates = records.map(function (r) { 
   r.CallDateTime = new Date(r.CallDateTime); 
   return r;
});
// validate CallDateTime is of Date type
console.log(typeof recordsWithDates[0].CallDateTime.getMonth === 'function')
```